# Hibernate Criteria uniqueResult

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

My sql query is somethin like below

```
SELECT count(1),tran_nbr FROM AAA WHERE P_D IN (3,4) AND
 DTE_OF_ISS BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('01/31/2015' ,'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

And i have written a hibernate query like this.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AAA.class).setProjection(Projections.rowCount());


   criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("(P_D IN ('4'))"));

   if (reportsForm.getFromDate() != null && reportsForm.getToDate() != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("DTE_OF_ISS = to_date('"+ utils.convertDateToString(reportsForm.getFromDate()) + "', 'MM/dd/yyyy')"));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("DTE_OF_ISS <= to_date('"+ utils.convertDateToString(reportsForm.getToDate()) + "', 'MM/dd/yyyy')"));
    }

  criteria.setFetchSize(100);
criteria.setMaxResults(500);
    listResult = criteria.list();

   listResult = criteria.list();
    int count = ((Long) criteria.uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

when i see the "show_sql" the query looks like this.

```
select * from ( select count(*) as y0_ from Schema.AAA this_ where (P_D IN ('4')) and DTE_OF_ISS = to_date('01/01/2014', 'MM/dd/yyyy') and DTE_OF_ISS <= to_date('01/31/2015', 'MM/dd/yyyy') ) where rownum <= ?
```

No idea from where the addition select coming and rownum? Please help me out..

Comment: That's because of the `setMaxResults`. Let Hibernate generate the SQL, don't try to control all the exact SQL details yourself.